# Trivial Lambda function works on AWS but not on `sam local start-api`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

There are so many moving parts here I'm not sure which ones are relevant. The Lambda function is defined like this:

```js
import {APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult} from "aws-lambda"
import {DynamoDBClient} from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb"

export async function handler(event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
  console.log("Starting")
  // new DynamoDBClient({})

  console.log("Ending")
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
    body: `Hello, CDK! You've hit ${event.path}\n`,
  }
}
```

and when I uncomment the line `new DynamoDBClient({})` it fails locally, but when it's commented out, it runs fine. On AWS it runs fine. The failure looks like this in the terminal:

```
Invoking src/subscribe.handler (nodejs14.x)
Skip pulling image and use local one: public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs14.x:rapid-1.37.0-x86_64.

Mounting C:\Users\pupeno\Code\ww3be as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: 49bbe24b-9694-4743-970c-9c7c0f81efe1 Version: $LATEST
Function 'SubscribeLambda' timed out after 3 seconds
END RequestId: 49bbe24b-9694-4743-970c-9c7c0f81efe1
REPORT RequestId: 49bbe24b-9694-4743-970c-9c7c0f81efe1  Init Duration: 0.35 ms  Duration: 3000.00 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms        Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 12
8 MB
Invalid lambda response received: Lambda response must be valid json
2022-02-09 17:29:01 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2022 17:29:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 -
Lambda Function 'SubscribeLambda' source code has been changed, terminate its warm container. The new container will be created in lazy mode
```

Is it timing out after 3 seconds? I'm confused by that.

The Lambda function is being created a CDK stack in `infra\compute-stack.ts` that looks like this:

```js
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib"
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda"
import * as apigw from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway"
import {Construct} from "constructs"
import {StateStack} from "./state-stack"
import path from "path"

interface ComputeStackProps extends cdk.StageProps {
  readonly stateStack: StateStack
}

export class ComputeStack extends cdk.Stack {
  public readonly hcEndpoint: cdk.CfnOutput

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: ComputeStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props)

    const subscribeFunction = new lambda.Function(this, "SubscribeLambda", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(process.cwd(), ".."), {exclude: [".run/**", "cdk.out/**", "test/**", "infra/**"]}),
      handler: "src/subscribe.handler",
      environment: {
        TABLE: props.stateStack.table.tableName,
      },
    })

    props.stateStack.table.grantReadWriteData(subscribeFunction)

    // defines an API Gateway REST API resource backed by our "subscribeFunction" function.
    const gateway = new apigw.LambdaRestApi(this, "Endpoint", {
      handler: subscribeFunction,
    })

    this.hcEndpoint = new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "GatewayUrl", {value: gateway.url})
  }
}
```

And the way I'm running it locally is by first creating a `.template.yaml` with:~

`cdk synth --no-staging --app "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts compute-app.ts" *Compute > .template.yaml`

also deploying the stack for my DynamoDB database and putting the details in .locals.json, but that's not even being touched in this tiny example. Then I run it this way:

`sam local start-api --template .template.yaml --env-vars .locals.json --warm-containers EAGER --port 3001`

Any ideas what's going on? What's wrong?

Happy to add more details about other moving pieces, I'm not sure what else is relevant since such a tiny hello-world-like function requires so many moving pieces.

Comment: debug idea:  test the handler stand-alone with `sam local invoke` to rule out the lambda execution as a source of error.

Comment: Might be because SAM doesn't know which credentials to use to initialize the SDK client?

Comment: @fedonev In my case `sam local invoke` works but the OP's case still does not!